# When you recreate a Feature, do you need to uninstall and re-install it?

Tags: 7, features

When you recreate a Feature, do you need to uninstall and re-install it or is it OK to just delete the feature folder and paste the new on in its place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just delete the feature folder and paste the new folder. You should not get any issues.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of deleting the folder just download the tar.gz file and extract it in the folder where the features folder is there. I would automatically merge the changes.

Comment: You just need to overwrite the old files with your new files from features.  This can be done automatically under advanced options and generate button.  You must have your folder writable though.

Comment: I have trouble with this method in the past.  Although doing this will overwrite all duplicate files and add all missing files, it will not delete files (potentially full of hooks) that do not exist in the newer archive file.